Logout wordress user and redirect to affiliate link
i have a WordPress affiliate site, i need to add a link for affiliates to be able to register downline while logged in, but since the WordPress registration form cannot be accessed by logged in users, I am trying to create a function to log the user out on click of button that links to the wordpress logout url /wp-login.php?action=logout, remove the confirmation page and redirect to the signup page using the affiliate referral link.  i need to capture the user id before logout and pass into the variable of the before redirecting.
so far i have this code the button (/wp-login.php?action=logout">Log out) it works well, the redirect fuction works well, the only problem i am having is that the user id is not being sent to the browser.  this is what i get in the browser " https://www.website.co/join-now/?ref=%20wp_get_current_user
Please i need to capture the current user id and append it to the redirect url.
add_action('check_admin_referer', 'logout_without_confirm', 10, 2);
function logout_without_confirm($action, $result)
{
    
     $user = wp_get_current_user();

    if ($action == "log-out" && !isset($_GET['_wpnonce'])) {
        $redirect_to = isset($_REQUEST['redirect_to']) ? $_REQUEST['redirect_to'] : '/join-now/?ref=echo".$user->user_login."';
        $location = str_replace('&amp;', '&', wp_logout_url($redirect_to));
        header("Location: $location");
        die;
    }
}

when i click the button, it logs out but i am unable to get the user id in the URL. please i will appreciate some help
I expect that when I click on the add affiliate button, it logs the current user out and redirect to the affiliates referral link so his id is captured as the referrer.

You can use the function wp_logout_url(), now you will need to allow the URL redirection:
add_filter( 'allowed_redirect_hosts', 'allow_redirect' );

function allow_redirect( $allowed ) {
    $allowed[] = 'externalsite.com';
    return $allowed;
}

Then, use wp_logout_url() in a link:
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( 'https://externalsite.com' ); ?>">Logout</a>

More info about: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_logout_url/

the major issue is that i am not getting the user id appended to the redirect url.  everything else works well

@etimgeorge If you want to append the user id, you can do something like:  <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( 'https://externalsite.com/?userid=' . get_current_user_id() ); ?>">Logout</a>
